# Unable to use mcrypt extension in php 5.2.9

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am using **xampp 1.8.1** and I integrated **php 5.2.9** to it by using the patch delivered by [apachelounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/)

I have started apache it was started normally but it shows some errors with the php extensions

> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:42] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_mcrypt.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:42] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:42] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:42] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_pgsql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:42] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_ps.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:42] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_paradox.dll' - The specified module could not be found.in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_mcrypt.dll' - The specified module could not be found.in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_pgsql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_ps.dll' - The specified module could not be found.in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-Nov-2012 10:56:45] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Secoweb\xampp\php\ext\php_paradox.dll' - The specified module could not be found.in Unknown on line 0

I refereed [Stackoverflow question in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271408/enable-mcrypt-on-php-install)  . and  I followed the steps but it was also a failure.

I had these dll's in **xampp/php/ext** folder, I tried by putting dll's in system32 folder. I was also not working.

I am using mcrypt for password encryption and decryption. So please help me to start php with mcrypt extension.

Thanks in advance

Jishnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to find out the solutions for the issue.

It was due to the **libmcrypt.dll dependency issue**, So I put the libmcrypt.dll into apache folder and restarted the apache. also I commented all the unwanted extensions so phperrorlog is clean now.

**libmcrypt.dll** is present in the **php** folder I fixed the issue by moving the dll into **apache/bin** folder

Now **Xampp 1.8.1** is working perfectly with **php 5.2.9**