# Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension with-XAMP

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

I downloaded a free library management system from Github when I open the URL via localhost or turning the Laravel server it says that "requires the Mcrypt PHP extension".
I have updated the composer but not work.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtc5P.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable Mcrypt on PHP Install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271408/enable-mcrypt-on-php-install)

Comment: I did that too but still have the error

Comment: Did you restart PHP after changing the settings?

Comment: Yeah I did three time.

Comment: Can you show the Mcrypt part from php.ini

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension/16832214